# IOS how to download image from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a URL image on the server.
I use this to save avatar.
How to I can use URL to download image and set in my ImageView.

Comment: I would recommand *SDWebImage*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to use this code to download image in background

**Make sure your url contains a image and it is valid url**

```
NSString *strImgURLAsString = @"imageURL";
[strImgURLAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgURLAsString];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (!connectionError) {
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        // pass the img to your imageview
    }else{
        NSLog(@"%@",connectionError);
    }
}];
```

Comment: I don't know why it get img = nil.

Comment: please check out my edits

Comment: Sorry! I cannot mark, I not have reputation.

Comment: you do not required reputation to mark answer correct. can you see the right arrow near the vote count?

Comment: Thanks for mark my reply as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myImageURL];
NSString *imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myImage.png"];
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I don't know why it get imageData = nil.
So, how to I can load image and set in myimageview

Comment: show me your URL ImageView code  plz

Comment: oh my god! 
I'm sorry, because my link is wrong!
I'm so sorry and thank you!

Comment: welcome Durian and acpet also my answer plz